# Todo list in react - how would you move an item completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am very new to coding and I am trying to work on a Todo list.
Once I click on an item, I would like to have the option to mark it complete and move it to the "Completed Items" column...

Here is how it looks code wise so far :

in my App.js

```js
 

  function markAsCompleted(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    // ask if an item is complete
    // if it is, move it to completed items 

    }

<li className = 'activities' onClick={markAsCompleted}
                key = {a.text}  > 
                    <FaPaintBrush onClick={ (i) => toggleColor (a) }/>
                     <div 
                     style = {{color: a.color }}>
                      Activity: {a.data.text},
                      Type: {a.data.area}
               </div>
               </li>
```

Here is my completed items component, for now not displaying anything else than a title

```js
function CompletedItems (props) {
    
    
  
      return (
       
        <label>
        Completed items

        </label>
       
    );
  }
  export default CompletedItems;
```

Here is how it looks on the Localhost :)
[Local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yjVw.png)

Thank you so much for your help!
Julie

Comment: There are a lot of ways to go about it and a lot of to-do-list examples in react.   
If I had to implement something like this on the fly, I'd try to make it as simple as possible, so don't take this suggestion as the "best" approach.   
I would create an <Item> component with "complete" as boolean state. onClick => setState(!previousState)  (or just setState(true)), whatever fits.  
And then in your main component, have a state with all the items in a list Item[].
then you can use conditional rendering on whether complete is true or not

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Leviathan !!